# PowerShell freezing when calling script

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powercli

I wrote a GUI to centralize some little PowerCLI-Scripts. In one of those little scripts, I check the  vCenter health with a "Get-VAMIService" statement. If i just run this script, everything works fine, but if i call the script from my GUI both, the GUI and the called script, freez. I figured out, that the everything freezes at this "Get-VAMIService" statement.

```
$service1 = Get-VAMIService -Name applmgmt
```

I have already tried it with DoEvents().

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
```

It dosen't matter if i run it in the ISE or the normal PowerShell btw.

Does anyone know, why the script freezes, when called from the GUI-script, but runs fine when executed by itself?

Edit: I forgot to mention, that I use the VAMI-Summary from William Lam.
https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2017/01/exploring-new-vcsa-vami-api-wpowercli-part-1.html

A GUI with one button to call the script for recreating:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$window = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$window.Width = 540
$window.Height = 400
$window.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$window.MaximizeBox = $false


$windowButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$windowButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,40)
$windowButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (75,75)
$windowButton.BackColor = "white"
$windowButton.ForeColor = "Black"


$Textfieldbut1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Textfieldbut1.text = "Test"
$Textfieldbut1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(22, 120)
$Textfieldbut1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (300,50)
$Textfieldbut1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")


$window.Controls.Add($windowButton)
$window.Controls.Add($Textfieldbut1)

$windowButton.Add_Click({
    ."$PSScriptRoot\Script.ps1"

})

[void]$window.ShowDialog()
```

Here is the called script where it freezes. It freezes at "$services = $vMonAPI.list_details()".

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction ignore -confirm:$false | 

Out-Null

Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core

$vcenter = "vCenter Name"
$path1 = "C:\PS2\securestring1.txt"
$path2 = "C:\PS2\"
$localadmin1 = 'administrator@vspheresh.local'
$password1 = cat $path1 | convertto-securestring -Key (1..16) 
$global:credlocal = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $localadmin1, $password1
Connect-CisServer -server $vcenter -credential $credlocal
Write-Host "Connected..." -ForegroundColor "green"
$vMonAPI = Get-CisService 'com.vmware.appliance.vmon.service'
$services = $vMonAPI.list_details()
$services

Disconnect-CisServer -Force:$true -confirm:$false | Out-Null
```

Edit 2: If I call the script from a script without a GUI it works totaly fine. Only when i klick the Button in the GUI-script it freezes and crashes.

Comment: Mind adding a minimal code example so others can reproduce your error without beginning to write a GUI script and so on?

Comment: Have you validated your are indeed connected via `Connect-CisServer`? Normally the hang is for about 5 minutes before it times out with connection to the vcenter

Comment: I have added a GUI-Script.
The connection works fine.

Comment: Try recreating the problem without the VAMI module https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've exchanged the code with a new one to recreate the problem.